# Can I define an alias key for NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

I rename the key of NSMutableDictionary, but I want to access it by old name as well, Can I define an alias key.

Comment: Just have both keys reference the same value.

Comment: I think it should work in some scenario, and the price is to maintain to keep the insistent of the two keys.

Comment: Dictionaries does not have aliases. You could save all renames in separated dictionary where key is old key and value is new key and make search there when needed key didn't find in the original dictionary.